What are the architectural differences between `composeApp/` and `shared/`?
When starting a new Kotlin Multiplatform with Jetbrain's wizard, there are 3 modules created when you chose to use "Compose Multiplatform", namely composeApp/, shared/ and server/.
Now composeApp/ and shared/ both have multiple sources sets commonMain, androidMain and iosMain. I fail to understand what goes under composeApp/ and what goes under shared/. What do each of these modules mean and their relationship with one another?

For this, I'm assuming you created the project with both 'Server' and 'Client' (either Android, iOS or Web) options.
When you choose this option, it will create the modules you mentioned and they have the following purpose:

Shared - Host shared logic between Client and Server applications
Server - Host serve logic with KTor
Compose - Host client logic which will use Compose to Render

Their relation is that both server and compose uses classes/interfaces/logic from the shared module.

Also, as both shared and compose modules are configured as Kotlin Multiplatform, they will have commonMain, iosMain and androidMain.
However, if you want to create some new "business logic" that is "UI Agnostic" and will be used by both the client and server side, it's a good practice to created it in shared module (so it can be called from both modules).
If you want to create a new UI, you should do it in the compose module.
